# SQL to identify the IDs for which some columns are different with a filter

Tags: sql, select, ddl, vertica

Let's assume I have a following table:

```
   id | temp_id | status     | date
------+---------+------------+-----------
0  10 | 123-abc |   closed   | 2021-11-01
1  12 | 123-abc |   open     | 2021-10-26
2  14 | 123-abc |   null     |    null
3  15 | 123-abc |   open     | 2021-10-26
4  17 | 123-abc |   open     | 2021-10-26
5  20 | 456-xyz |   open     | 2021-10-29
6  22 | 456-xyz |   null     |    null
7  20 | 789-uvw |   closed   | 2021-10-06
8  22 | 789-uvw |   closed   | 2021-10-06
```

I want to write a query to find all the temp_ids from a table where values for some columns (status, date) are not matching for the same temp_id and if at least one of them have a status = 'closed'

Here for this table, it should return only 123-abc in the temp id column like:

```
   | temp_id | 
---+---------+
0  | 123-abc |
```

Here, I don't wish 456-xyz coming as a result because even though id 20 and 22 have same temp_id and different values for status, date - but neither have the status 'closed' so that's not required for end result. While, for 789-uvw, both records (7 and 8) have the status closed and same date too, so it is not required either.

What I have thought so far:
I am using row_number partitioned by temp_id but in this above example how do I compare row_number 1 to 5 for temp_id = '123-abc' and see if any of them have status = 'closed'. I tried any() but it throws error, I guess I am not using it correctly. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result using the same format!

Comment: "some column" is not very helpful...

Comment: @jarlh - I am fixing it now

Comment: @andrew - I provided additional details, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple using `HAVING`:

```
select
temp_id
from
<your table>
where temp_id in (select temp_id from <your table> where status = 'closed')
group by temp_id
having count (distinct status) > 1
or count (distinct date) > 1
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0d2eea0faf8044d30670dbc908126a12)

Comment: Hi Andrew - I tried it and the syntax is correct but it returns me blank. Also, thanks for guiding me on this. I was making it more complex than it is I believe.

Comment: @trojanhorse - I added a fiddle. Using your sample data, it returns your desired result.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I see, it works. I was trying the same on the local data where there are multiple filters. I also did it using CTEs and that is also working fine.